# Only one thread running from ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool of size 5

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to learn the behavior of ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool. I assign work to the executorService and expect it to be done by multiple threads.

The scenario is simple.

I initialize thread pool of size 5. And  then I assign work to executor service.
 But I see only one thread is handling the work.

Shouldn't it be handled by more than one thread available in the pool.
Code:

```
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        int k =0;
        while (k++<5){
        System.out.println("Active Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the complete code
[jdoodle.com/a/bRP](http://jdoodle.com/a/bRP)

The output I got is

```
Active Thread pool-1-thread-1
Active Thread pool-1-thread-1
Active Thread pool-1-thread-1
Active Thread pool-1-thread-1
Active Thread pool-1-thread-1
```

The output I was expecting was:

More threads participating in the work.

**EDIT**

Essentially I want to replicate this behavior using ExecutorService

```
package Threading;

public class ThreadDeleteme {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Work w = new Work();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(w);
        t1.setName("Thread 1 ");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(w);
        t2.setName("Thread 2 ");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(w);
        t3.setName("Thread 3 ");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        System.out.println("ThreadDeleteme.main()");
    }

}

class Work implements Runnable {
    Integer i = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (i < 100) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + i);

                i++;
            }
    }
}
```

Can you please tell me where my understanding is going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You didn't give the pool 5 tasks, you gave it one task that loops 5 times.

Comment: If you read the javadocs (for the Executor  interface) you will see this code snippet `Executor executor = anExecutor;
 executor.execute(new RunnableTask1());
 executor.execute(new RunnableTask2());`

Comment: Can you please check my modified question. I want my single piece of work to be done by multiple threads from the thread pool. Like I am doing in my EDIT section

Comment: `executor.execute(t1);`

Comment: If you want a piece of work to be done by multiple threads, you need to first divide the work into several sub tasks that can be executed in parallel and then submit the tasks to Executors for parallel execution. Java won't use multiple threads to execute sequence code in parallel.

Comment: @ScaryWombat you are passing thread (t1) to execute method. I want my Work w to be handled by multiple threads from thread pool. passing "w" to execute get the job done by using only one thread

Comment: How should the threadpool decide on how to split your code among multiple tasks? Black magic? that's your job, unfortunately, and this is usually the most difficult task to divided a larger problem into multiple smaller problems. Ok, in your example it's trivial, but what happens if you have a more complex task?

Comment: @Geek Then create **inside** the loop a new task for each `i`.

Comment: @AKSW in my edit I have created three threads and they are assigned one task.  Is it wrong to do it like this. If it is not wrong then I want to achieve the same using thread pool .

Comment: @Alex can you point me to some example of what you are suggesting. Is it the fork join feature . Between are you saying that one task can only be handled by one thread?

Comment: @Geek, I don't have any examples. But you may image that you need to do a work by 5 people. Then you first need to divide your work into 5 sub tasks and then assign it to those people. The same thing is for your program. This is a design issue.

Comment: You assigned the **same task** to thread, that's obviously wrong and not tread-safe. Create a new `Work` object for each thread, then all three threads will execute the same loop from 0 to 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created ONE thread that prints current thread name ( =Active Thread pool-1-thread-1) 5 times.
Make 5 runnable instance and submit them to the executor service

[UPDATE]

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Work w = new Work();
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        executorService.submit(w);
        executorService.submit(new Work()); // set new runnable tasks here
        executorService.submit(new Work());
        System.out.println("ThreadDeleteme.main()");

    }

}

class Work implements Runnable {
    Integer i = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (i < 100) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + i);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

For naming issue,
You'll have to use an ExecutorService implementation that allows you to set the ThreadFactory [1](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) used to create threads, Pass an instance that creates threads with the proper names.
[ThreadFactory DOC](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html)

Comment: Can you please check my modified question. I want my single piece of work to be done by multiple threads from the thread pool. Like I am doing in my EDIT section

Answer (score 5):

you need to create a number of tasks, instead you created just a single one only.  So, something like the following should work for you. But, if the task finishes faster than you create another one, it will probably not hit all the threads in any case.

```
   ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    int k =0;
    while (k++<5){
        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 System.out.println("Active Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        });
      }
 };
```

Comment: Can you please check my modified question. I want my single piece of work to be done by multiple threads from the thread pool. Like I am doing in my EDIT section

Comment: @Geek your edited code doesn't make sense in its current form. All threads are accessing the same object, that will lead to concurrency issues. Also, your example is too simple. In general, you have to split your problem into smaller subproblems, that's something the threadpool doesn't do for you. It would be easier if you show what you really want to parallelize.

Comment: @Geek yes, your 'update' will behave similar to the 'thread' example you provided. you could have used the same 'work' as well. But it is is a very simple and not  very useful example. In real world you will also need to take care of synchronizations between threads and concurrent access to the data, .... EexcurtorService in your case will limit the number of threads which process your tasks (to 5), in the thread example nothing will do it. You are scheduling only 3 tasks for execution, so 2 threads are wasted in any case.

Answer (score 1):

You're using same thread to print loop ,but not calling method with different thread, thread doesn't divide task automatically you have to assign task to them.Your `main()` methods look like

```
public static void main(String[] args){

     ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5); //here you defined thread pool size
     executorService.submit(new Work()); //added first thread to pool
     executorService.submit(new Work()); //added second thread
     executorService.submit(new Work()); //added third thread
 }
```

And your Work class:

```
class Work implements Runnable {
int i = 0;

@Override
public void run() {
    while (i < 100) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + i);

            i++;
        }
}
```

}